# How to insert data from second row in tableview in iphone

Tags: iphone

i  need your help.I need to insert data dynamically but insertion should be from the second row in the tableview in iphone.How can i do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to fetch the data from the array w r t (indexPath.row -1), in case you are populating the table with an array

Answer (score 1):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

if(indexPath.row==0)
{
 //return blank cell;
}

//add cell contents

return cell;

}
```

Comment: i did this but there is one problem that whenever i insert my array in able then the insertion is started from the 0 index.

Comment: use [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1]

Answer (score 0):

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }

        // Configure the cell.
        NSIndexPath *path1 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row+1 inSection:indexPath.section];
        [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:path1];

        return cell;

}
```

I do not tested it but it should work, try it out